# Python: only 1 loop excuted in a nested for loop

Tags: python

I have a python script, with a nested `for` loop

```
    HostList = file('trylist.txt')
    DestHostList = file('trylist2.txt')
    for DestHost in DestHostList:
            DestHost = DestHost.strip()
            for HostName in HostList:
                    HostName = HostName.strip()
                    try:
                            if DestHost!=HostName:
                                    print HostName,DestHost

                            print "one loop finishes"
                    except Exception, e:
                            ExceptionHost.write(HostName+' -  '+DestHost+':    '+str(e)+'\n')       
                            print "exception"
                            #traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

The outer `for` loop appears to be only executed once.
What could be the potential problem?

Comment: `DestHostList` has only one element?

Comment: many elements, not just one

Comment: If the outer loop only loops once, then that list has only one element. The inner loop is iterating over `HostList`.

Comment: but DestHostList has 3 elements

Comment: Sorry @DSM, I may have missed an indentation in a recent edit I was trying to help with...

Comment: What is your exact output of the loop?

Comment: I tried `python -tt`, still the outer loop is excuted for once

Comment: BTW, I updated my codes, they are files

Comment: @misteryes: `python -tt` only reveals whether inconsistent whitespace is being used.  If your program ran at all, that's good news, as it suggests that your strange-looking whitespace isn't the issue.  Now that you've updated the code to show that they're files and not lists (despite the names), what do you get if you add `print repr(DestHost)` immediately after `for DestHost in DestHostList`?

Comment: And you're saying that there are more lines than that in `trylist2.txt`?

Comment: yes, `trylist2.txt` and `trylist.txt` have the same content

Comment: you can try the script in your PC, just make a trylist.txt with 3 lines

Comment: I don't get it. so if you put three lines: `aaaa`, `bbbb`, `cccc` on both file, then you will get `bbbb aaaa`, `cccc aaaa` and then the program stops. But, what I expect are `bbbb aaaa`, `cccc aaaa`, `aaaa bbbb`, `cccc bbbb` and `aaaa cccc` `bbbb cccc`

Comment: @misteryes: ah, that's probably it.  [Although note that what you just said isn't compatible with only getting one output from `print repr(DestHost)`.]  You think that if you nest `for` loops over files, then the inner one will jump back to the start after you've looped over it, which isn't true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer loop executes more than once, but only in the first iteration it has things to do.  In the rest, the inner loop does not execute, leaving you with the impression it's only running once.

The problem is that you open the first file, `trylist.txt`, and read it entirely in the first iteration of the outer loop.  On the second iteration, the file object (which is iterator-like) has already been "consumed".

Try:

```
HostList = file('trylist.txt').readlines()  # now it's a list of lines, not an iterator
DestHostList = file('trylist2.txt')
for DestHost in DestHostList:
    DestHost = DestHost.strip()
    for HostName in HostList:
```

If the file is huge and you want to avoid storing it in memory, you can reopen it every time:

```
DestHostList = file('trylist2.txt')
for DestHost in DestHostList:
    DestHost = DestHost.strip()
    HostList = file('trylist.txt')
    for HostName in HostList:
```

Also, it is good practice to open files in python using a `with` statement.

Comment: And you want to open the file with `open`, not with `file`.

Comment: @Matthias I know using `open` is the recommended way, but I don't see why the OP should worry about such a minor detail, when his real concern is making his simple script work...

Comment: Make something work is good. Make something work as it is intended to work is better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have exhausted the second file in the inner loop after the first pass.

As I can see you were trying to troubleshoot the issue with `try ... except ...`. But since the file read operation is outside the block, you missed it.

Here is a solution with reading in advance all file content. I hope it will help:

```
host_list = file("trylist.txt").readlines()
dest_host_list = file("trylist2.txt").readlines()

for h in host_list:
    for d in dest_host_list:
        h,d = h.strip(),d.strip()
        if h != d:
            print h,d
```